# Unit Testing MongoDB WriteOneAsync() Fails to create document

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, async-await

I'm a tad perplexed writing a unit test to test a MongoDB WriteOneAsync(). 
I have tried running the unit test on a MongoDB example that writes a document to the MongoDB but it is failing to write the document to the database.

Below is my code. I tried awaiting mc.savetomongo(); but it cannot await a void.

This is just an example I put together to demo the problem. My actual code uses a an interface and data layer but same problem.

I should say that the code works fine if I call savetomongo() from within its own project class or from a form project. The problem seems to only exists when unit testing.

Any help woiuld be massivly appreciated!

Many thanks

I have a unit test project as follows,

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using mongotestclass;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public async void TestMethod1()
        {
            Mongoclass mc = new Mongoclass();

           mc.savetomongo();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a seperate class project containing the following.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

namespace mongotestclass
{
    public class Mongoclass
    {
        protected static IMongoClient _client;


    protected static IMongoDatabase _database;

        public async void savetomongo()
        {
            Uri con;
            Uri.TryCreate("mongodb://" + "DESKTOP-263RHTL:27017", UriKind.Absolute, out con);

            _client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
            {
                ConnectTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0),
                Server = new MongoServerAddress(con.Host, con.Port)
            });

            _database = _client.GetDatabase("SchemaTest3");

            var document = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "address" , new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "street", "2 Avenue" },
                        { "zipcode", "10075" },
                        { "building", "1480" },
                        { "coord", new BsonArray { 73.9557413, 40.7720266 } }
                    }
                },
                { "borough", "Manhattan" },
                { "cuisine", "Italian" },
                { "grades", new BsonArray
                    {
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "date", new DateTime(2014, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                            { "grade", "A" },
                            { "score", 11 }
                        },
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "date", new DateTime(2014, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                            { "grade", "B" },
                            { "score", 17 }
                        }
                    }
                },
                { "name", "Vella" },
                { "restaurant_id", "41704620" }
            };

            var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in the fact that your test ends prematurely, due to the fact that you're not awaiting on any of the asynchronous tasks. Thus, you have a race condition between the insertion of the document and the termination of the test.

What you actually need to do is expose an `async Task` operation, instead of `async void`, which will allow you to `await` up the call chain of your test:

```
public Task SaveToMongoAsync()
{
    Uri con;
    Uri.TryCreate("mongodb://" + "DESKTOP-263RHTL:27017", UriKind.Absolute, out con);

    _client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
    {
        ConnectTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5, 0),
        Server = new MongoServerAddress(con.Host, con.Port)
    });

    _database = _client.GetDatabase("SchemaTest3");

    var document = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "address" , new BsonDocument
            {
                { "street", "2 Avenue" },
                { "zipcode", "10075" },
                { "building", "1480" },
                { "coord", new BsonArray { 73.9557413, 40.7720266 } }
            }
        },
        { "borough", "Manhattan" },
        { "cuisine", "Italian" },
        { "grades", new BsonArray
            {
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "date", new DateTime(2014, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                    { "grade", "A" },
                    { "score", 11 }
                },
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "date", new DateTime(2014, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                    { "grade", "B" },
                    { "score", 17 }
                }
            }
        },
        { "name", "Vella" },
        { "restaurant_id", "41704620" }
    };

    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
    return collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
}
```

And now make your test `async Task` as well and `await` in it:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestMongoInsertionAsync()
    {
        Mongoclass mc = new Mongoclass();
        await mc.SaveToMongoAsync();
    }
}
```

As a side note I would improve this test, and actually return a value you can assert on in your test to make sure the document was correctly inserted.

Comment: Hello Yuval. Thanks for the extremely fast response!!! Your answerer worked a treat! I did originally await the unit test but I had to set return types to Task<bool> return true. This seemed a bit messy although it worked. I also do use an assert to test the write but left it out of my example here for clarity. Your answer makes perfect sense! and I guess really only applicable to unit tests which expect a return type of some description as all worked fine when calling the method from outside the unit test.  Many thanks again Nigel